# Angular UI Grid: How to bind HTML with the cellTemplate, AND dynamically build HTML that ng-click works on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Here is a plunker as requested-
http://plnkr.co/edit/tIkBFO?p=preview

I am using the controllerAs pattern. I have been using the cell template with a filter($sce) to sanitize, and then build HTML. For the life of me, I cannot get the ng-click to register to my controller.

I can change the cell template to cellTemplate:`'<button ng-click="grid.appScope.user.delete(\'works!\')">X</button>'`-> This works.

Is there anyway to NOT use cell template and still get to the controller? Details column is where I am having issues.

Thanks for reading!

Related issues-
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4116

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4886

Here is the code-

```
        var user = this;

        user.gridDefs = [{
                            displayName: 'User ID',
                            name: 'userId',
                            width: "10%"
                        }, {
                            name: 'firstName',
                            width: "15%"
                        }, {
                            name: 'lastName',
                            width: "15%"
                        }, {
                            name: 'email',
                            cellTemplate: '<div ng-bind-html="COL_FIELD |trustedclean"></div>',
                            width: "25%"
                        }, {
                            name: 'username',
                            width: "15%"
                        }, {
                            name: 'details',
                            cellTemplate:'<div ng-bind-html="COL_FIELD |trustedclean"></div>'
                            width: "20%"
                        }, ];

user.gridData = _.map(dataFromSvc.users, function(user) {
                    var buildDetailsString = buildDetails(user.uid);
                    var object = {
                        'userId': user.Id,
                        'firstName': user.firstName,
                        'lastName': user.lastName,
                        'email': '<a href=\"mailto:' + user.primaryEmail + '\">' + user.primaryEmail + '</a>',
                        'username': user.uid,
                        'details': '<div><a href=\"#/viewuser/'+user.uid+'/true\">View</a>/<a ng-click=\"user.deleteUser('+user.uid+')\">Delete</a></div>'
                    return object;
                });

    user.deleteUser = function(uid) {
                    console.log(uid);

                };
```

Here is the HTML-

```
<div id="grid2" ui-grid="{ data: user.gridData, columnDefs:user.gridDefs}" class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: If you can create a plunkr, I'd take a look at it

Comment: Sorry took me a while to get it working- http://plnkr.co/edit/tIkBFO?p=preview

Comment: Looks like you're doing it correctly with the cellTemplate. Is there a reason you don't want to use it? That's kind of what it is for... If you don't like your HTML in your js, you can use an external file just as easily...

Comment: I show users different options between view, and delete depending on what role they have. Just thought it would be easier to not be doing it in the template. I guess drop the filter, add a conditional around what the cell template will be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering my own question-

Do not sanitize, and use ng-bind on ui-grid. Use the template to manage your cells. This is what I did.

```
cellTemplate:dynamicTemplate
```

Answer (score 0):

This is enough to bind the html containing string

```
{ field: 'message', displayName : 'Message Description', cellTemplate: '<div ng-bind-html="COL_FIELD"></div>' }
```